# ssh_askpass Permission denied, when using GNU parallel, even when using nohup

Tags: ssh, sshd, gnu-parallel

I am trying to run code across a network of external nodes.
I have access to the 'main' node through `ssh`, and can execute a `parallel` script that divides the jobs over the cluster of 5 available nodes. 
I have a `bash` script that contains the `parallel` command, among other necessary components.

The final command I am using looks similar to this.

```
parallel -S node0,node1,node2,node3,node4 --ssh-delay 0.25 --delay 0.5 'run {1} {2}' ::: foo ::: bar
```

However, the cluster that I am working on is known for hanging up relatively frequently, e.g., after ~5 minutes of idle time, I get a `Broken pipe` error, and the `ssh`- the connection is broken. It is why I execute the upper bash script (that contains the above `parallel` line) using `nohup`, which should keep the ssh-connection alive.

But because my actual code takes considerable computation time, I get errors related to broken ssh-connections:

```
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory^M
Permission denied, please try again.
```

even though connecting from (e.g. `node0` to `node1`), the boss node to the other nodes does not require a password. 
This results in `parallel` complaining that there are no more job slots available and a warning that there are no logins possible:

```
parallel: Warning: There are no job slots available. Increase --jobs.
parallel: Warning: Using only -1 connections to avoid race conditions.
parallel: Warning: ssh to node0 only allows for 0 simultaneous logins.
parallel: Warning: You may raise this by changing /etc/ssh/sshd_config: MaxStartups and MaxSessions on node0.
parallel: Warning: You can also try --sshdelay 0.1
```

I believe that there is something finicky going on that prematurely closes the ssh-connection to the other nodes within the cluster, possibly the result of closing the connection to the boss node, `node0`.

I have tried to establish a connection using `ssh-agent`, `ssh-copy-id`, and `sshpass` as per the GNU parallel tutorial, as well as setting the `MaxStartups` and `MaxSessions` parameters in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, but to no avail.
Even more, if I reduce the computation time of the code, then the parallel command is perfectly executed and works as expected.

Is there something I can do to ensure that the ssh-connection does not break when the program executed by `parallel` takes considerable time, or is there something else going on?

Comment: Am I correct that everything works if `run` takes less than 4 minutes to run and the problem only shows up with long running jobs?

Comment: How are you using `ssh_askpass`? Can you post the configuration that causes it to be called? GNU Parallel is not tested extensively with `ssh_askpass` so it there can easily be some issues with interaction between the two.

Comment: Yes indeed, the problem shows up only when running long jobs.

I am not sure how `ssh_askpass` is used, since I do not call it myself directly. I assume it is called by `parallel`. Is there perhaps some configuration I can check?

Comment: It is not called by GNU Parallel: it calls ssh. So something in your ssh-config causes this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the connection alive you can often use `ServerAliveInterval`. It can be set in `.ssh/config`.

Comment: I have indeed tried this and it seems that the server does not hangup anymore. 

However, I still get many warnings from GNU parallel that there are no job slots available:

`parallel: Warning: There are no job slots available. Increase --jobs.`

Comment: Can you increase to `--sshdelay 5`? I have the feeling something in your `ssh` connection causes it to overload.

Comment: Problems disappeared after putting the `ServerAliveInterval` on all nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the origin of the error, namely that the ssh-key that was used to access the different nodes was incorrect.
Thus, the problem was neither with GNU parallel nor with nohup.

Let me first illustrate the setup in a bit more detail, as to understand the problem. 
I first connect from my `local` computer to a 'boss'-node, `boss` which is connected to several slave nodes `slaves`. 
By enabling ssh-forwarding when using `ssh` to connect to the `boss`-node, further ssh-connection wrongly used the key from my `local` computer. 
Hence, when I broke the connection between the `local` and the `boss`, the `boss` had no access to the correct ssh-key in order to establish connections to the `slaves` nodes.

This problem was resolved by generating a new public ssh-key using `ssh-keygen` and distributing this key over the other nodes by adding it to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.
The result is that when the connection between the `local` and the `boss` is broken, the `boss` can still establish an ssh-connection to the `slaves` by using its own public key.

Since GNU parallel uses ssh to establish connections, once the keys were setup correctly, the permission (and other related) issues disappeared. Using `nohup` with setting the `ServerAliveInterval 60` in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` resolves all disconnection issues, and allows disconnection from the `boss` node while processes are kept running.